Implementing Field Level Security for Fields in Standard and Custom Objects
I'm currently working on enhancing data security in our Salesforce app by implementing Field Level Security (FLS) for fields that get updated in both standard and custom objects. I want to ensure that sensitive data is properly protected, but I'm also concerned about the scope of implementation.
Specifically, I have two questions:

Is it necessary to implement Field Level Security (FLS) for fields even in test cases?

2.Should constants describing these fields also adhere to FLS?
Any insights, best practices, or recommendations on this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!


Is it necessary to implement Field Level Security (FLS) for fields even in test cases?

In the general sense, no. Unit tests are generally meant to test application logic, not necessarily field level security. Codifying FLS into unit tests makes them very hard to maintain.

Should constants describing these fields also adhere to FLS?

Also no. Constants are for your code to use. What would it mean to have a field token disappear to your code? You'd then have to check every field access to see if it was null before using it.

In the general sense, you should just use Security.stripInaccessible whenever possible, rather than checking individual FLS as your code runs. This is more efficient overall.
